# PHP strip_tags(): Strip all but images from a certain domain?

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

I would like to know if it is possible to strip ALL tags from a form the user has submitted, apart from  tags from a certain domain.

I have a form which is mostly an "About Me" field where the user can share some information about himself/herself. I am currently stripping and securing the data for a MySQL insert using this:

```
$data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags((string)$_POST['f_ab_me'])));
$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $data);
```

Now I know strip_tags allows the possibility of allowing specific tags by using:

```
strip_tags($data, 'img');
```

But can I somehow tell it to NOT remove IMG tags that have the attribute "source" from "http://i.imgur.com/....." for example?

I do not want to allow the user to upload pictures on my server since I do not want to have to use that much bandwidth, but I would like to give them the option to still add images from imgur.com (which strips EXIF information automatically). What I also do not what to do is have a ton of input-boxes where the user can enter a link in each one, that just wouldn't look very nice in my opinion.

This is why i am asking if it is possible to somehow control it programmatically, maybe with a regular expression?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You can't with strip tags.... you can tell it what tags to strip or leave, but not based on attributes of those tags

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @MarkBaker but can you maybe tell me how I could do this? Thanks!

Comment: Strip all tags except img tags using strip_tags, then you'd need a regex or use dom to strip remove all the unrequired images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, using `strip_tags` function is not a right way, cause if your user wanna write anything that looks like HTML you just cut it off. Not so friendly, huh? :)

Using `htmlentities` would be enough to avoid HTML injections in user-entered content.

As of your question you can do next:

1. Using Regexp replace all `i.imgur.com/*` images to something like `[IMG=*]`
2. Then apply `htmlentities` to user content.
3. When rendering content just use Regexp again to turn your `[IMG=*]`code back to `img` tag.

I'm not very familiar with Regexp but there is working pattern I wrote:

```
echo preg_replace("#<img (.*?)src=(\"|\')http(s)?://i.imgur.com(.*?)(\"|\')#U", "[IMG=http://i.imgur.com$4]", $content);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daniilicious! I understand, this is a great place to start of with, I'll have a go at it now.

Comment: Hey, quick question, howcome this RegExpression works on regexr, http://regexr.com/39j6h but not when I use:
    preg_replace("/<img (.*?)src=(\"|\')http(s)?:\/\/(?!i.imgur.com)(.*?)(\"|\').*\/?>/", " ", $_POST['f_ab_me']);
Thanks!

Comment: @user3751393 as I can see on regexr your exp doesn't work too, deleting ?! before i.imgur.com make it works on Regexr and in PHP as well

Comment: Hey, hmm, how would I go at selecting the opposite then? I would like to select all img tags that do not contain i.imgur.com in the src. I thought ?! did the opposite of what comes next. Thanks!

Comment: @user3751393 Sorry, didn't realized that you wanna select opposite at first. `preg_match_all("/<img (.*?)src=(\"|\')http(s)?:\/\/(?!(i.imgur.com))(.*?)(\"|\').*\/?>/", $content, $matches);` - this one works fine for me as inverted select